# Where can I find public SMS or Twitter datasets

Tags: twitter, dataset, sms

I am in the need for large SMS or Twitter datasets. Anybody knows where I might be able to find such things.

Thanks.

Comment: controversy topic. Is it moral to use these paid SMS datasets. Did the users in the list approve the use ? I don't think so.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor, You have abused your privilege for being able to downgrade other's question by downgrading my question. If was a simple question that you can just answer professionally.

Comment: It's not me to -1 . Calm down friend.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this 
http://www.infochimps.com/tags/twitter

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
There is an SMS spam collection to those who are in wanting a similar datasets as I am. Here is the link http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/

Comment: Did you find some other dataset also ? Above link contains 5K only

Answer (score 0):

Try using below links to get twitter datasets

https://data.world/datasets/twitter

https://archive.org/search.php?query=collection%3Atwitterstream&sort=-publicdate

Also you can use Twitter API to collect tweets.